# Loading scripts synchronously, the first uses "src", the second is an inline script

Tags: javascript, html, performance, browser

I have the following HTML file:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
const first = document.createElement("script");
first.setAttribute("src", "./remote.js");
first.async = false;

const second = document.createElement("script");
second.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`console.log("second");`));

document.body.appendChild(first);
document.body.appendChild(second);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The content of `remote.js` is

```
console.log("first");
```

The console output is

```
second
first
```

I want the first script to be completed before the second.
This is a simplification of much more complex code, for which performance is critical. Therefore, while I know I can use `document.write`, or to register to `first.onload` and only then append the second script. Both have performance issues I would like to avoid.

Comment: What do you think is the issue with `first.onload`? Especially if it's not an external script but some code that you want to execute after the script has been loaded?

Comment: If you just want to have the script running, there's nothing wrong with that. However, adding the script to the DOM early allows the script streaming thread to parse the script earlier. See https://blog.chromium.org/2015/03/new-javascript-techniques-for-rapid.html

Comment: But you don't want to run another script that had to be loaded after the remote.js, you have inline code?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question; The goal was to load scripts with optimal performance, without changing load order. So, the script first needs to run first, and second should run second as soon as first is done.

Comment: I'm saying that you have no second script to load. You have an inline script that loads a remote script, and contains code that should run when that remote script is done. There is no good reason to create a third `<script>` element for that.

Comment: As I wrote, this is a simplification of a more complex scenario, where the user can have any number of scripts, which should run in order. Check it out if you want :) https://github.com/capriza/capp-cache

Comment: Ah, ok, unfortunately neither the example in the question nor your answer were using multiple external scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other who might have a similar issue, I found a decent solution, by using [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs).
The idea is to use the `src` attribute to set the content of the script. The browser considers it to be a url, and therefore the behavior is consistent.

The line

```
second.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`console.log("second");`));
```

Should be

```
second.setAttribute("src","data:text/javascript,"+`console.log("second");`)
```